# How to add frequency to barplot for inbuilt barplot r function

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I have a dataframe as follows:

`tab=cbind(AR, PR, GR)`

tab

```
          AR    PR   GR
High      340   301  182
Low       97    112  271
Moderate  211   235  195
```

I created barplot of the data using barplot function

```
barplot(cbind(AR, PR, GR), col=c("purple", "green", "cyan"),beside=FALSE)
legend("topleft", legend = c("High", "Low", "Moderate"), fill =  c("purple", "green", "cyan"))
```

[image: output]

Now, I want to add the frequency inside the barplot. I tried using `labels=tab`, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to draw them on using `text`. Here's a full reprex:

```r
AR <- c(High = 340, Low = 97, Moderate = 211)
PR <- c(High = 301, Low = 112, Moderate = 195)
GR <- c(High = 182, Low = 281, Moderate = 195)

barplot(cbind(AR, PR, GR), col=c("purple", "green", "cyan"), beside = FALSE)

text(x = rep(c(0.7, 1.9, 3.1), each = 3),
     y = c(apply(cbind(AR, PR, GR), 2, \(x) c(0, cumsum(head(x, -1))) + x/2)),
     label = c(AR, PR, GR))

legend("topleft", legend = c("High", "Low", "Moderate"),
       fill =  c("purple", "green", "cyan"))
```

[image]

Since the question is tagged with ggplot2, here's how you could achieve a nicer aesthetic result using ggplot:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(AR, PR, GR) %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "rows") %>%
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value, fill = factor(rows, c("Low", "Moderate", "High")))) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
            size = 5) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel1") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_line())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: `ggplot2`, has thrown me an error ```Error in `pivot_longer_spec()`:
! Can't combine `Var1` <factor<a5be0>> and `Freq` <integer>.```

Comment: @batman that error isn't from ggplot, but from pivot_longer. It suggests that the data you are passing in is a `table` rather than a matrix as in your example. If you convert your table into a matrix using `as.matrix` then re-run the code it should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `as.matrix` did not work but `as.data.frame` worked... !!!